# MVVM & Dagger - Injection of activity scoped model causes stale instances issues

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger

I am working on a fairly complex app based on MVVM. The app has multiple activities. One of these activities, the one this question is about, uses many fragments and each fragment has its own ViewModel.

The activity itself also has a ViewModel.

Inside the ViewModels I use an instance of Model which provides domain logic, and it is handled by Dagger. The model has an Activity scope. This means that each ViewModel receives the same instance of Model during creation as long as the same activity instance is running.

So far so good.

Then a configuration change happens.

When a configuration change happens, my activity and all the fragments are of course destroyed. However the ViewModels survive. Which is expected.

Since the Model instance is scoped with Activity scope, from this point onward, all newly created ViewModels (for fragments not yet opened before the config change) will receive a new instance of Model from Dagger.
However, the ViewModels created before the configuration change will still have the old Model instance. Remember they were not destroyed during configuration change.

I've been thinking about a proper solution for this but what I am doing is pretty much basic MVVM, how can there be such an issue? Did anybody ever face it?
Am I using MVVM wrong? Is the model always supposed to be scoped with Application scope? That would solve the issue but seems a rather limiting option.

Answer (score 0):

Here your model's lifecycle should not depend on the Activity or Fragment, but it should depend on ViewModel. If you create a repository abstraction for fetching your model and inject into ViewModel, you will always be on the safe side.

BTW, passing Activity/Fragment scoped data to ViewModel may cause memory leaks if somehow that model has a reference to Activity/Fragment itself.